# jquery - how to copy content to textarea

Tags: jquery

I have form with textarea that allows users to add replies

I would like to add button to each reply (class "quoteMsg"). clicking on it will copy the reply content (have class="replyMsg" ) + the writer name+date (inside SPAN tag) to the textarea (name="msgText") + add "$" note before and after the content

Here is the HTML example:

```
<form method="post" action='index.php' id="submitReply">
    <p><textarea name="msgText"></textarea> <span></span></p>
</form>

<section class="replyBox">
        <article class="left">
            <header>
                <h2>Re: Voucher Release Prblm - Comm</h2>
                <span>By esther  <strong>&raquo;</strong>  21-10-2014 12:06</span>
                <a href="#" class='quoteMsg'>Quote</a>
            </header>   

            <div class="replyMsg">
                If will happen again, I will open a new track<br />
            </div>
        </article>
</section>

<section class="replyBox">
    <article class="left">
        <header>
            <h2>Re: Voucher Release Prblm - Comm</h2>
            <span>By esther  <strong>&raquo;</strong>  23-07-2014 11:19</span>
            <a href="#" class='quoteMsg'>Quote</a>
        </header>   

        <div class="replyMsg">
            OK, thanks
        </div>
</section>
```

should i do something like this:

```
<script>    
$('.quoteMsg').click(function() 
{
    var msgContent = parents("article").find(".replyMsg").val(); 
    //alert(msgContent);

})
</script>
```

?
if yes - how do i put in inside the textarea field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) attribute to find the element like this:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
 $('.quoteMsg').click(function()  {
  var txt = $(this).closest('.replyBox').find('.replyMsg').text();
  $("textarea[name='msgText']").val($.trim(txt));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action='index.php' id="submitReply">
    <p><textarea class="msgText" name="msgText"></textarea> <span></span></p>
</form>

<section class="replyBox">
        <article class="left">
            <header>
                <h2>Re: Voucher Release Prblm - Comm</h2>
                <span>By esther  <strong>&raquo;</strong>  21-10-2014 12:06</span>
                <a href="#" class='quoteMsg'>Quote</a>
            </header>   

            <div class="replyMsg">
                If will happen again, I will open a new track<br />
            </div>
        </article>
</section>

<section class="replyBox">
    <article class="left">
        <header>
            <h2>Re: Voucher Release Prblm - Comm</h2>
            <span>By esther  <strong>&raquo;</strong>  23-07-2014 11:19</span>
            <a href="#" class='quoteMsg'>Quote</a>
        </header>   

        <div class="replyMsg">
            OK, thanks
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what do i need to change to clicking on the button "Quote" won't jump my page to the top?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way

```
$('.quoteMsg').click(function() 
{
    var msgContent = $(this).closest("article").find(".replyMsg").text(); 
    console.log(msgContent);
});
```